# SQL in query : why query returns different results?

Tags: sql, postgresql

This is table:

```
CREATE TABLE position 
(
    id BIGINT NOT NULL
    ,remark CHARACTER VARYING(255)
    ,uid CHARACTER VARYING(255)
    ,version INTEGER
    ,weight CHARACTER VARYING(255)
    ,CONSTRAINT position_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
    ) 其中每添加一条数据生成一个uid
    ,"version" initialize = 1;

每修改一条数据
    ,uid不变
    ,version + 1;
```

I need a query of the same UID, version number the maximum data.

This is my sql:

```
select * 
from position as c 
where c.id in (select max (d.id) from position as d group by d.uid);
```

but it returns the wrong data.

```
select * 
from position as c
where c.version in (select max (d.version) 
                    from position as d 
                    group by d.uid);
```

Why does this query return different results?

Comment: [How do I ask a **good** question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

The first query will take the maximum id from the position table and only return position rows where that id matches

The second query will take the maximum version from the position table and only return position rows where that position matches

i.e. if you have the following

```
ID     Position
1      1
2      2
3      3
4      3
```

the first query would return row 4 only.  The second would return rows 3 and 4

Comment: Why does this query return different results?

Comment: Because you have 2 rows with position 3 (i.e. max position), but only 1 row with ID 4 (i.e. max ID)